# Zend Framework 2 Translator locale vs language (fallbacks per language?)

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, zend-framework2, translation

I'am currently working on the localization of a bigger project but ran into quite some issues. Let's explain in more detail:

Within my application I determine the user's language by using the HTTP Accept Header which works pretty fine. This locale is used for the initial translation by invoking \Locale::setDefault($locale);. However, the user should be able to switch the language. I thought about creating a deep link with a language parameter like http://www.example.com/en/ in the switcher since I have to provide language specific (not country specific) links for the client as well. Config-files share the pattern en_US.php pt_PT.php etc.

Now, the following questions popped up:
 - Which locale should I select per language. For instance  there is pt_PT and pt_BR for language pt. Should the language win over the accept header locale? Or should I keep locale and language separate.
 - Can I define language specific defaults? For instance: Locales en_US and en_GB share  the language en, pt_PT and pt_BR the language pt.
- Finally, I could also create a language file for each possible locale, although the file for en_GB and en_US would look exactly the same?

I would be very glad, if you could share some thoughts if you'd also run into the same trouble. Thanks a bunch, Chris